# Loading elements in a dropdownlist according to another dropdownlist choice

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

Imagine a drop down list of States:

```
Florida
Washington
Maryland
Maine
```

According to the chosen state, I need to load a collection of Cities within that state.

My database schema is already created for this situation:

```
State             City
---------         -----------
ID                ID
Name              Name
                  StateID
```

I'm thinking about using ajax to fetch  JSON response from an ActionMethod and use jQuery to load those values into the city drop down list.

Is this a good path to follow?

Since I need to get the selected city ID (*in order to process what city the request came from*), how do I assign not only the text, but also the ID to the drop down list item?

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common question and is referred to as a 'cascading dropdown list'

Try googling

'asp.net mvc jquery ajax cascading dropdownlist'

and you should find plenty of info, tutorials etc